# Deploying Google Cloud function from a Google Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

When attempting to deploy a simple function, I am running into a 403 error. Here is my full yaml:

```
steps:
# Install Dependencies
- name: 'python'
  id: Pip install
  args: ['pip3', 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt', '--user']
# Run Tests
- name: 'python'
  args: ['python3', '-m', 'pytest', 'functions/folder_a/test/']
# Deploy Cloud Functions
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  id: 'helloFunction'
  args: ['functions', 'deploy', 'hello', '--source' , 'functions/folder_a/main.py',
           '--runtime' , 'python37' ,'--trigger-http']
```

[image: Log]

Step one finishes fine but step two errors here.

```
$ gcloud info

Account: [projectname@appspot.gserviceaccount.com]
Project: [projectname]

Current Properties:
  [core]
    project: [projectname]
    account: [projectname@appspot.gserviceaccount.com]
    disable_usage_reporting: [True]
```

I tried adding the following permissions to the above account in IAM:

- Cloud Build Service Agent
- Cloud Functions Developer
- Cloud Functions Service Agent
- Editor

When Google Build is running, which service account is it using? How can I change the permissions to allow automatic deploying of functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Cloud Build to deploy Cloud Functions is documented in https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/testing#continuous_testing_and_deployment

From that page the guidance is:

> - To deploy Cloud Functions, you might want to assign the Cloud Functions Developer role to the Cloud Build service account (PROJECT_NUMBER@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com).
> - If you use the Cloud Functions Developer role, you also need to grant the Cloud Functions Runtime service account (PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) the [IAM Service Account User role](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles#adding_the_iam_service_account_user_role_to_the_runtime_service_account).

The Cloud Build service account is PROJECT_NUMBER@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com, if you look for it in the console there's only going to be one service account with `*@cloudbuild*`