# Correct permissions for Google Cloud Build to deploy a Cloudfunction in a separate project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-iam

We have separate GCP projects for "build" and "prod" environments. I would like to use Cloud Build for the "build" project to deploy a Cloud Function in the "prod" project, following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-cicd?authuser=1#functions-prepare-environment-python).

Notably, I added the "Cloud Functions Developer" role to the build service account in the build project and the "IAM Service Account User" role to the PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com account as noted in the docs and in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56482192/deploying-google-cloud-function-from-a-google-build), when running a build, I get:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden], message=[The caller does not have permission]

A simplified example of my cloudbuild.yaml is

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['source', 'repos', 'clone', 'a_mirrored_repo', '--project=build-xxxx']

 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
   args: ['functions', 'deploy', 'some_function', '--trigger-http', '--runtime', 'python37', '--project', 'prod-yyyy']
```

I am able to deploy my fucntion to prod using the gsutil command line utility from my laptop, and I am able to use my cloudbuild.yaml to deploy this function to the *build* project. But I'm unsure what roles I need to assign to what accounts to enable the build project to deploy the cloudfunction to the prod project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deploy the function in the prod project then the Cloud Build service account of the build project must be added as a "Cloud Functions Developer" in the prod project. If I understand your description correctly, then you've set it in the build project.

Specifically: in the GCP console, in the prod project, under IAM > members add a new member named `[build-project-id]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` and add the role "Cloud Functions Developer" to this member. At this point attempting to deploy may result in an error message:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403],
>   code=[Forbidden], message=[Missing necessary permission
>   iam.serviceAccounts.actAs for prod-xxxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
>   on project prod-xxxx.
>
> Please grant
>   prod-xxxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com the
>   roles/iam.serviceAccountUser role.
>
> You can do that by running
>   'gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding prod-xxxx
>   --member=prod-xxxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser'

The command suggested in the error message is slightly incorrect. The correct syntax is:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding prod-xxxx --member='serviceAccount:[build-project-number]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com' --role='roles/iam.serviceAccountUser'
```

Comment: This got me unblocked. I'll edit your answer to include the specific steps I took so that when need to figure it out again in 6 months, it's there.